# how can i make Dejavu to support CJK fonts

Tags: php, pdf, unicode, pdf-generation, fpdf

I'm currently using FPDF to create a PDF and tFPDF to allow for unicode characters. But when I'm trying to display some Japanese characters its showing some rectangle boxes instead of showing the actual Japanese font.

Currently I'm using DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf for the font.
I tried by adding msjh.ttf in my font folder but no luck.
What should I need to do to make characters like Japanese to show up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys its working for me now.I have used HanaMinA font to support JAPANESE characters.
Actually the Hanazono fonts (HanaMinA, HanaMinB) have full support for all 3 extensions and include 96k+ glyphs.
Actually it will display all Asian characters including Korean, Chinese and Japanese